# How to display nearby places ATM,Hospital or restaurant in google map using Angular 2 or Angular 4?

Tags: angular, google-maps, geolocation, google-geolocation, geomap

In my web application, i want to show the near by ATM or restaurants using google map API.
I am using following this link https://angular-maps.com/ I displayed the map. In current location how can I show the near by ATM or restaurant using Google map API? if this possible for angular 2 or angular 4? For example an ATM API.

Comment: did u find the solution?

Comment: yes, Actually I followed some link and achieve this .. I forgot the link. shard my GitHub link  try to use [Check this Link ](https://github.com/periyasamy17/angular4Geolocation)  Make sure this will help you, Thanks @JamAndJammies